# Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Tags: php, video, youtube, warnings

I'm using the following code in my WordPress site to display the latest Youtube video from my account using rss:

```
<?php
include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/rss.php'); // path to include script
$feed = fetch_rss('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UrbanGAME/uploads'); // specify feed url
$items = array_slice($feed->items, 0, 1); // specify first and last item
?>

<?php if (!empty($items)) : ?>
<?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>

<object width="96%"><param name="movie" value="<?php echo str_replace("watch?v=","v/", $item['link']); ?>&hl=en_GB&fs=1&"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="<?php echo str_replace("watch?v=","v/", $item['link']); ?>&hl=en_GB&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="96%"></embed></object>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It works. However, some of the times I get this error when it does not work:

```
 Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /wp-content/themes/theme1/header.php  on line 173.
```

Also I'm using the above code twice, for 2 spots on the site for 2 different accounts. One is in the my header.php file and the other in my footer.php file. When 1 works, the other does not, and of course I get an error/warning for the other one as well, just referring to that file and a different line. I have tried messing with the code and still nothing. Could the problem be with something in my code?

Additional info:

php: 5.3.2

host: crazy domains (http://www.crazydomains.com.au/)

apache: 2.2.15

Comment: Obviously whatever is happening is within `fetch_rss`. You should give the code for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it may not work is because `$feed->items` may not be an array(based on the `fetch_rss` call).

To check if something is an array, you can do:

`is_array($feed->items);` // returns true or false

If it is an array, you can then call `array_slice()`

The better solution however, is to check the `$feed` variable to make sure it returned what you are looking for before processing.

Comment: This will cure the symptom, not the disease.

Comment: Added a better solution.

Comment: by `$fetch` you mean `$feed`?

Comment: Yes, ah I need to get some sleep :X

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$feed->items` may or may not be an array.  That all depends on how `$feed` gets assigned, which depends on whats happening inside `fetch_rss`

Although tis somewhat oblique to your problem, it appears you have some superfluous code.  You do the slice to get the first element the array alone, and then you iterate on a list with just that one element?  Instead you can simply perform whatever you like on that first element.

```
<?php
include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/rss.php'); // path to include script
$feed = fetch_rss('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UrbanGAME/uploads'); // specify feed url
$firstItem = exists($feed->items[0]) ? $feed->items[0] : null;
?>

<?php if ($firstItem) : ?>
<object width="96%"><param name="movie" value="<?php echo str_replace("watch?v=","v/", $item['link']); ?>&hl=en_GB&fs=1&"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="<?php echo str_replace("watch?v=","v/", $firstItem['link']); ?>&hl=en_GB&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="96%"></embed></object>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. Instead what had happened is the rest of my template stopped working, few parts appeared and most importantly the video portion did not appear either. I do understand a bit of what you're saying. This just puzzles me as why it works about 98% of the time and then the other 2% like once every 2 weeks or now I think it has been once a week I get this warning/error message.

Comment: then your getting the `null`.  it doesnt solve initial problem, which is no one knows whats happening in `fetch_rss`

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem with an RSS feed related to a theme I'm using.  On the admin side, the code is supposed to display more themes by the same artist, however I'm getting the same array_slice error, because $feed->items is null.

The link to the RSS feed is working properly, and there is information at the address.  So, I started looking around, and I found that the problem is with the RSS, not the code (well, the original problem.  It's still a problem that that error is displayed).  I pointed the `fetch_rss()` command at a different feed, and it works fine.

Until the artist adjusts his feed to work with the command, there's nothing I can personally do.  But if you're having trouble getting this command to work with your *own* feeds, try making sure the feeds are in the required format for this Wordpress command.

Sorry to post on an old question, but there are no direct answers elsewhere on the web.